# Error: Configuring Next.js via 'next.config.ts' is not supported. Please replace the file with 'next.config.js'

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am building typescript next project. if I keep this config file as `next.config.js`, I get a warning in `tsconfig.json` saying "next.config.ts not found". so tsconfig.json has warning sign on the `{}`.

If I change the extension to `.ts`, when I start the project, I get this error:

"Error: Configuring Next.js via 'next.config.ts' is not supported. Please replace the file with 'next.config.js'.
"

I am confused and I do not what to do.

ts.config.json

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,

    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

next.config.ts

```
const path = require("path");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = {
  env: {
    AUTH0_NAMESPACE: process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE,
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },
};
```

Comment: can you post the contents of your tsconfig.json and scripts you use to build it? right now I cannot reproduce the issue, please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski you are right. I edited

Answer (score 10):

It seems that using `next.config.ts` slows down bootup, since you have to compile it yourself, or at least that's what the members of the next.js repo said.

There was an issue (more like a request) to support `next.config.ts` natively.
[Here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5318) is the issue about it, it has some solutions from other developers